# Should beef be cooked before adding to the pot for Stroganoff?

Tags: meat, slow-cooking

I'm following [a recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/slow-cooker-beef-stroganoff-i/) for Beef Stroganoff in a slow cooker.  The recipe does not say whether I should cook the stewing beef at all before adding it to the slow cooker.

I tend to thoroughly brown meat for things like chili or adding it to stir-fry, but should I be doing this for stroganoff*?  Or should I add it to the slow cooker raw?

*The question of 'how much browning' is mostly answered [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30283/chili-stew-is-it-necessary-to-cook-all-the-meat-before-adding-to-the-rest-of-t), though if Stroganoff is different enough from stew to make a difference, please answer as such.

Answer (score 1):

The recipe does not indicate that the beef should be browned before cooking and there is no need to. Per the instructions, all ingredients except the cream cheese go into the slow cooker together at the start. If it was intended for you to brown the beef first, that instruction would have been included.

The long, slow cooking should ensure that the meat will be tender and flavorful. Additionally, as in the picture of the dish, the beef cubes for stroganoff are on the small side. That should be additional insurance that your beef will be tender.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all for tenderness but flavorwise you will get a much better experience.

Brown it nicely (butter is your friend) and you will have a very meaty/nutty tasting stroganoff.

This is just repeating [SAJ14SAJ's answer in your question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30283/chili-stew-is-it-necessary-to-cook-all-the-meat-before-adding-to-the-rest-of-t).

Comment: SAJ14SAJ's answer from **where**?? If you're going to quote something, you should link to it.

Comment: @Catija Sorry it was linked in the question.

Comment: @Catija I'm not enough rep to mark for duplicates.

Comment: You can flag for duplicates though